# agm-polygon path is not getting updated on changes in component.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, agm, agm-core

**<agm-polygon [paths]="paths" [clickable]="false" >**

*Before changing path:*

```
paths = [
  [{ lat:  51.673858,  lng:  7.815982 ,label:"Node1"},
  { lat: 51.373858,  lng: 7.215982,label:"Node2" }],[
 
  { lat:  51.673858,  lng:  7.815982, label:"Node2"},
  { lat:  51.723858,  lng:  7.895982 ,label:"Node3"},]
]
```

The path is getting updated only once after initialization in . when I tried to update courses on click of marker to a different one.

```
 <agm-marker (markerRightClick)="onRightClickMarker(m)"></agm-marker>
```

the path is changing correctly in .ts which is a component file, but it is not getting updated in the template.

*After changing paths:*

```
paths = [
  [{ lat:  31.673858,  lng:  5.815982 ,label:"Node1"},
  { lat: 31.373858,  lng: 5.215982,label:"Node2" }],[
 
  { lat:  31.673858,  lng:  5.815982, label:"Node2"},
  { lat:  31.723858,  lng:  5.895982 ,label:"Node3"},]
]
```

Here is a stack blitz Example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/agm-angular-google-map-cedfud?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: share working example in stackblitz, or share more code!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/agm-angular-google-map-cedfud?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html Here is an example on marker click the path is changes but it is not getting updated